# Edit elements in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list with items that is loaded from firestore. Users can add new items etc. On each item i would like to have a edit button that toggles a small window, where the input is loaded and editable. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is the question related to data structure of firestore or frontend?

Comment: frontend on a web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you could build it as a list:

- [Material-UI List](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#checkbox) just add a modal dialogue for editing
- [material-UI Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#material-table) material-table is all set so you wouldn't need a modal dialogue, still you could do it like this [material-table examples](https://material-table.com)

There is a great tutorial on CodeRealm where guy is building something very similar to what you described. Take a look at it [Material-UI/React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm4LX5fJKZ8&list=PLcCp4mjO-z98WAu4sd0eVha1g-NMfzHZk)